# SIGALRM not triggered when reading big files

Tags: php, signals

How can I throw an exception when native php function takes forever to complete?
This code doesn't throw it after one second as I've initially hoped it would.

```
<?php

    declare(ticks = 1);

    $signal_handler = function () {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    };

    pcntl_signal(SIGALRM, $signal_handler, true);
    pcntl_alarm(1);

//while(1) {  }
file_get_contents("/dev/zero");
```

Comment: It works fine for me, at least with an infinite loop. Perhaps it behaves differently with a blocking synchronous call

Comment: Yes, so signals can't be reliably utilized from within php, which unfortunately leaves only outside intervention `timeout 1 php -r 'file_get_contents("/dev/zero");'`